# Is there a way to make it appear like a foreach look returns a value?

Tags: c#, lambda

This is something I have always wondered about, and looked up a few times but have never figured out.

So basically what I want to do is get something to this effect:

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>(){"a","b","c"};
string aString = foreach(string s in strings){ if (s == "c") return s;}
```

so then after that, aString has the value "c".

I have tried using lambda expressions, maybe I just cant get them to work right, or maybe there is just no way to do this.

And obviously I want to do something a bit more complicated than in my example above, but it will work the same way.

Possible? not possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the `FirstOrDefault` Extension method.

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>(){"a","b","c"};
return strings.FirstOrDefault(s=>String.Equals(s, "a"));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use LINQ (to objects):

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>(){"a","b","c"};
string aString = strings.Where(x => x.Equals("a")).FirstOrDefault();
```

The [`Where()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) methods iterates through the enumerable, and "returns" each element that satisfies the lambda. To get the first such element, you can chain on the [`FirstOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) method (which will return `default(string)` if no elements meet the criteria.)

As @MichaelGraczyk points out, you can actually reduce the call to only `FirstOrDefault()`, since it has an overload that accepts a predicate:

```
string aString = strings.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Equals("a"));
```

There are a number of other useful methods available, which you can [read about here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx).

Comment: You don't need the `Where`.  `FirstOrDefault` takes a predicate.

Comment: @MichaelGraczyk Good point, I always forget about that overload.

Comment: so this works well for the foreach look like in my question header, but is there a way to put a block of text that returns a value after an '=' (equal sign)?...or is that just bad practice..

Comment: @Toadums Yes.  return (variable = "value");  This does an assignment, then returns the rvalue that was assigned to the lvalue.

Comment: @MichaelGraczyk "value, lvalue, rvalue? Where do these come from?

Comment: err, I just mean that assignments are treated as expressions (program code with a type) in C#, and you can therefore return them.

Comment: @MichaelGraczyk Oh, that second quotation mark around value makes sense. I want to do it the other way though. like string s = {SOME LOGIC WHICH RETURNS A VALUE, assigning it to s}; ... if that is possible

Comment: That's what functions are for :)

Comment: fine! functions are ugly an overrated >.> thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 3):

It's kind of pointless in this particular example because you already know the string you want but in any case I think this is what you're trying to do...

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>(){"a","b","c"};

string aString = strings.Find((string s) => s == "a");
```